# Lightning record action to open prepopulated mail in user's client

Tags: lightning, email

On the **Standard Record page** for a CustomObject__c, I want to display a **button** or link (Quick Action, URL formula field, ...) that when clicked by the user opens the **users preferred email client** with a **pre-populated email** (To, Subject, Body) ready to extend and send.

If I don't have to I am more than happy to not need Aura Components and Apex Controllers for that. So the less I need the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a normal Formula field to do this:

```
HYPERLINK('mailto:'+EmailAddress__c+'?subject=Hello+There&body=This+is+an+example','Email Me')
```

For more information, see [Email Links on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#E-mail_links).

---

You can also make a quick action:

---

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" >
    <aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" />
    <force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}" targetFields="{!v.contact}" layoutType="FULL" recordUpdated="{!c.sendEmail}" />
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    sendEmail: function(component, event, helper) {
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
            contact = component.get("v.contact");
        a.href = "mailto:"+encodeURIComponent(contact.Email)+
            "?subject=Test%20subject"+
            "&body="+encodeURIComponent(contact.Description);
        a.click();
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: Didn’t expect it to be that easy. Thought formula fields wouldn’t allow mailto hyperlinks.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Honestly, I didn't either, so I had to test it first.

Comment: Naaah. Can't use that approach because the mail body must come from a Long Text field and those are not allowed in Formulas. I am also quite sure that the maximum length of URL parameters will restrict long email bodies.

Comment: Can you think of another "lean" solution. Maybe an Action component without Apex just using Data Services...

Comment: @RobertSösemann Added an example quick action version as well.